# Hebrew username

Tags: username

I need to add username in hebrew,

I have added this,

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_user', 'sanitize_user_with_hebrew', 10, 3 );

function sanitize_user_with_hebrew( $username, $raw_username, $strict ) {

$username = $raw_username;
$username = wp_strip_all_tags( $username );
$username = remove_accents( $username );
// Kill octets
$username = preg_replace( '|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username );
$username = preg_replace( '/&.+?;/', '', $username ); // Kill entities

// If strict, reduce to ASCII for max portability.
if ( $strict ) {
    $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-z0-9א-ת _.\-@]|i', '', $username );
}

$username = trim( $username );
// Consolidate contiguous whitespace
$username = preg_replace( '|\s+|', ' ', $username );

/**
 * Filter a sanitized username string.
 *
 * @since 2.0.1
 *
 * @param string $username     Sanitized username.
 * @param string $raw_username The username prior to sanitization.
 * @param bool   $strict       Whether to limit the sanitization to specific characters. Default false.
 */

return $username;
}
```

And this allows to add username in hebrew username, but I can't see the name in `users.php` in backend. I see blank.

My site is in Hebrew.

Thanks

Comment: How did you go with this @hkchakladar? Did the solution posted below help you?

Answer (score 0):

check this plugin [hebrew username](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hebrew-username/)

u need to use regex - `[\p{Hebrew}a-zA-Z]`